# JQuery: changing image in DIV on mouseenter/mouseleave on a link and looping

Tags: jquery, html

I'm struggling with two JQuery problems.
I have the following HTML structure:

```
    <div class="mouse-effect">
        <p>
        <a class="auto-01" href="#">Image 1</a><br>
        <a class="auto-02" href="#">Image 2</a><br>
        <a class="auto-03" href="#">Image 3</a><br>
        <a class="auto-04" href="#">Image 4</a>
        </p>
    </div>
   <div class="automotive">      
        <img class="auto-img" src="auto-00.png">
   </div>
```

What it should do:
mouse enter / leave:

1. On mouse enter: replace the image "auto-00.png" with the
   corresponding image in the class of "a", e.g.  "auto-01.png"
   .
   1b. Chance the link color to red.
2. On mouse leave: restore the image "auto-00.png".
   2b. Chance the link color back to default.

Automatic hovering:

1. One run-through: automatic loop over all "a"s, pretending a mouse enter, mouse leave.

   I figured it out to read the src-attributes ( ('class') and ('src') ) and to change it.

But I do not know, how to get it into a function and how to call it.

My idea was something like this:

```
$.fn.loop = function(startimage,div) {
    var newimage = $(this).attr('class'); //class from <a>
    var src = $(div); // <img "auto-img">
    var target = src.attr('src').replace(startimage,newimage);
    var link = $(this); // <a>

    link.css("color","red"); 
    src.fadeOut(200,function(){
     src.attr('src', target).on('load', function(){
        src.fadeIn(200);
        link.wait(600).css("color","");
        });
    });
    startimage=newimage;   

};
```

And then call it with:

```
$("div.mouse-effect p a").loop("auto-00",".auto-img");
```

This is the example for the loop.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all the class should not be unique.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com I heard that `id` should be unique and not the `class`

Comment: Also, I see all the classes are unique as well

Comment: FYI, you should set src of img after the onload event to still handle older browser and cached image

Comment: @Mr.Alien and what have I said??

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com *First of all the class should not be unique*

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com I can't see that the classes are unique...

Comment: @achterbahn what is class="auto-01",class="auto-02",class="auto-03"

Comment: Classes can have a unique name. Ids have to. But actually, you are using class as data. You should use attribute `data-src` instead and retreive your data with `$('...').data('src')`.

Comment: `<a>` does not have src indeed but HTML5 allow the use of `data-*` which is handlable by jQuery. Example : `<a href="#" class="link" data-src="image.png">LINK</a>` and retreive with `$('.link').data('src');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this i think:

```
$('.mouse-effect p a').mouseenter(function() {
  className = $(this).attr('class');

  replaceImg = '<img class="auto-img" src="' + className  + '.png">'

  $('.auto-img').replaceWith(replaceImg );
  $(this).css("color","red");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.auto-img').replaceWith('<img class="auto-img" src="auto-00.png">' );
  $(this).css("color","black");
});
```

Let me know if it worked.

**Edit :**

As Smoky below mentioned an other perhaps better way to do this is:

```
$('.mouse-effect p a').mouseenter(function() {
  className = $(this).attr('class');

  $('.auto-img').attr('src',className+'.png');
  $(this).css("color","red");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.auto-img').attr('src','auto-00.png');
  $(this).css("color","black");
});
```

Comment: It's better to do `$('.auto-img').attr('src', imageSrc);` IMO.

Comment: @Smoky I edited the above what do you think? better?